# How to connect to Presto JDBC in python?

Tags: python, jdbc, sqlalchemy, presto, presto-jdbc

I am trying to connect to Presto server in python using JDBC, but cannot find any guidance on how to do that. There are ways just to connect to Presto in python (e.g., standard approach in SQLAlchemy) or to connects to Presto JDBC in Java or R, but I could not find how to adopt those for the combo of Presto + JDBC + Python.

Comment: You might try using [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is possible, but I do not have example.
However, more native way would be to use: https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31294488)